# How beautifully to stop object property validation on the first error in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I have the following code:

```
    class User
    {
        /**
         * @Assert\Type(type="string")
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\Email()
         * @Assert\Length(max=255)
         */
        public $email;
    }
```

This object is filled from an API call. When validation takes place and property is filled with array value instead of string then NotBlank, Email, and Length validations continuing to work and I get "UnexpectedTypeException".

I want validation system just to add one error about wrong value type and stop there.

I've made custom constraint validator

```
    class ChainConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
        {
            if (!$constraint instanceof ChainConstraint) {
                throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, __NAMESPACE__.'\All');
            }

            $context = $this->context;
            $prevCount = $context->getViolations()->count();
            $validator = $context->getValidator()->inContext($context);

            foreach ($constraint->constraints as $constraintStep) {
                $errors = $validator->validate($value, $constraintStep);

                if ($errors->getViolations()->count() > $prevCount) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It works and I used it like this:

```
    @ChainConstraint(
        @Assert\Type(type="string"),
        @Assert\NotBlank(),
        @Assert\Email(),
        @Assert\Length(max=255)
    )
```

I have a lot of such classes in my project. Is there any more beautiful and requiring less code a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think this happens because you have type hints in your setters.

Comment: This class has no setters only one public field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from **Symfony 5.1** a [Sequentially constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Sequentially.html) is available.

> This constraint allows you to apply a set of rules that should be
> validated step-by-step, allowing to interrupt the validation once the
> first violation is raised.

Answer (score 2):

What about this :

```
$var = [];

$constraints = [
 new Type(['type'=>'string', 'groups'=> 'first-check']),
 new NotBlank(['groups'=> 'second-check']),
 new Email(['groups'=> 'second-check']),
 new Length(['min'=>2, 'groups'=> 'second-check'])]
    ;

$groups = ['first-check', 'second-check'];
$groupSequence = new GroupSequence($groups);
$error = $validator->validate($var, $constraints, $groupSequence);

if(count($error) > 0) {
    dd($error); // Contains 1 ConstraintViolation (Type) 
 }
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is works and for my case there would be 4 validation groups. Actually I  have model fields with more than 4 validation rules and it would require many validation code. But I will try this option.
Thank you

Comment: You’re welcome  Don’t forget to accept my answer

Comment: However, if the class has several properties to be validated, each having 'first-check' and 'second-check' constraints, then as soon as a property fails the first validation group, then the second group's validation will be skipped for all other properties as well. This may not be the desired behavior as in such case, a violation of a 'second-check' constraint on another property would not raise any error...
Anyone having another solution to stop validation at property level only ? (as opposed to class level)

Answer (score 1):

You may found some information in these issues which seem to be similar to the behavior you want to have:

- [Halt subsequent constraints on first failure #2947](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2947)
- [[Validator][GroupSequences] GroupSequences still execute next group if first fail #9939](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9939)

As described in these issues I think the best way to do it properly is to use [group validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html) even if it seems to be a bit clumsy to do it on every assertion.

Comment: As I understood this is the solution from the box. Although it will work I find this solution (validation groups) as very verbose when I have 5-10 constraints for some model field
Thank you